# Power BI - Show zero/null value on line chart with dates

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm using a simple table like this to make a report in Power BI:

| Order number | Order date | Turnover |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 30/1/2022 | 10 € |
| 002 | 30/1/2022 | 20 € |
| 003 | 2/2/2022 | 15 € |

I need to create a line chart showing all the dates, even where I have no data (no orders for that day). This is currently how is shown:

[image]

You can notice that the 1/2/22 and 3/2/22 are missing due to no order, but I want them to be visible and the value should be 0. This is also affecting the average line because it's calculated based on the days with data, but I need to put into account also the 0-turnover days.

I tried to use the "Show items with no data" on the date dimension and switch the X axis from Continuous to Catergorical and the other way around. I also tried to create a new metric like this:

> Total Turnover = IF(ISBLANK(SUM(Orders[Turnover (EUR)])), 1, SUM(Orders[Turnover (EUR)]))

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your business requirement correctly, you are going to need to do three things:

1. Make sure you have a date-dimension table in your model. Build the relationship based on your `[Order date]` column.
2. Refactor your `[Total Turnover]` measure as such:

```
Total Turnover = 

VAR TotalTurnover = SUM( Orders[Turnover] )
RETURN

IF(
    ISBLANK( TotalTurnover ),
    0,
    TotalTurnover
)
```

3. Build your line chart using the `[Date]` column from your date table.